# Add another tuple to a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following tuple of tuples:

```
my_choices=(
         ('1','first choice'),
         ('2','second choice'),
         ('3','third choice')
)
```

and I want to add another tuple to the start of it

```
another_choice = ('0', 'zero choice')
```

How can I do this?

the result would be:

```
final_choices=(
             ('0', 'zero choice')
             ('1','first choice'),
             ('2','second choice'),
             ('3','third choice')
    )
```

Comment: That's a tuple of tuples, not a list of tuples.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Build another tuple-of-tuples out of `another_choice`, then concatenate:

```
final_choices = (another_choice,) + my_choices
```

Alternately, consider making `my_choices` a list-of-tuples instead of a tuple-of-tuples by using square brackets instead of parenthesis:

```
my_choices=[
     ('1','first choice'),
     ('2','second choice'),
     ('3','third choice')
]
```

Then you could simply do:

```
my_choices.insert(0, another_choice)
```

Comment: "*Alternately, consider making my_choices a list-of-tuples*", the reason being lists are mutable, contrary to tuples. And if tuples are immutable, it's because this allows more efficient operations.

Answer (score 34):

Don't convert to a list and back, it's needless overhead. `+` concatenates tuples.

```
>>> foo = ((1,),(2,),(3,))
>>> foo = ((0,),) + foo
>>> foo
((0,), (1,), (2,), (3,))
```

Comment: I thought you couldn't change tuples?

Comment: You can't---but you can redefine them :)

Comment: *You can't---but you can redefine them*, actually what you're doing is assigning a new tuple object to the existing variable `foo` (which happens to already hold another tuple object, but that's irrelevant). So we need to understand "redefining" as a trivial assignment. +1

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, use the tuple concatenation

i.e.

```
final_choices = (another_choice,) + my_choices
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the "unpacking operator" (*) to  create a new tuple

`tpl = ((2, 11), (3, 10),)`

`tpl = (*tpl,  (5, 8))`

`print(tpl) #prints ((2, 11), (3, 10), (5, 8))`

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a tuple of tuples, not a list of tuples.  Tuples are read only.  Start with a list instead.

```
>>> my_choices=[
...          ('1','first choice'),
...          ('2','second choice'),
...          ('3','third choice')
... ]
>>> my_choices.insert(0,(0,"another choice"))
>>> my_choices
[(0, 'another choice'), ('1', 'first choice'), ('2', 'second choice'), ('3', 'third choice')]
```

list.insert(ind,obj) inserts obj at the provided index within a list... allowing you to shove any arbitrary object in any position within the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_choices=(
         ('1','first choice'),
         ('2','second choice'),
         ('3','third choice')
)

new=('0','zero choice')

l=[item for item in my_choices]
l.insert(0,new)
my_choices=tuple(l)
print(my_choices)
```

1. create a list from element of my_choices tuple
2. Now you can insert the new tuple element at the first position (index 0)
3. Create a new tuple from list named list and assign it to "my_choices"
4. Print my_choices variable (a tuple of tuples)

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.