# Inserting tuple into a tuple

Tags: python, loops, tuples

I am using a loop to create tuples, and I would like to insert these tuples into a big tuple.

Assuming my input is (1, 2, 3), which is generated from every loop, my expected output is ((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)).

I tried multiple ways but still cannot figure out how to do it.

```
big_tup = ()

for i in range(2):
    tup = (1, 2, 3)

    # this will cause AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'
    big_tup.insert(tup) 

    # this will combine all tuples together, output: (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
    big_tup += tup

    # this will make duplicates of (), output: (((), 1, 2, 3), 1, 2, 3)
    big_tup = (big_tup,) + tup
```

I would be very appreciated if anyone can help me solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add another tuple to a tuple of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523048/add-another-tuple-to-a-tuple-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a tuple here; you want a list. Tuples are immutable; they can't be added to once they've been created.

Lists however can be `append`ed to:

```
big_list = []
. . .
big_list.append(tup)

print(big_list)  # [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: It helps! Thank you so much! I didn't notice that tuple is read only. Because my expectation is to get a tuple, now I think I should use your idea and then use tuple(big_list).

Comment: @JaneChen That is perfect.

Comment: @JaneChen That can work. Note though that turning a list into a tuple can be expensive. If `big_list` gets too big, it may prove more efficient to generate into call to `tuple`: `tuple(tup for _ in range (2))`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360314/3091398) it is recommended to use list of tuples instead of tuple of tuples.

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523128/3091398). You just need to use the below code if you are very particular to create a tuple of tuples.

```
big_tup = ()

for i in range(2):
    tup = (1, 2, 3)
    big_tup += (tup,) # this doesn't insert tup to big_tup, it is actually creating a new tuple and with the existing tuples and new tup using the same name

print(big_tup)
# ((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3))
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/FlashyFearlessRay)

Comment: Thanks so much! Before I posted this question I have read your link but (((), 1, 2, 3), 1, 2, 3) comes out. It seems that I converted tup and big_tup by mistake. You really help me figure it out!

Comment: @JaneChen Glad it helped. I would still recommend to use list of tuples instead of tuple of tuples.